# Repeated group captures more matches than specified

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to match the following sequence, line by line:

- start of line
- maybe some space
- the `Kd` string
- at least one space, maybe more
- either 3 or 4 `float` numbers whose format may be messy
- maybe some space
- end of line

The problem is that the 4th sample is also captured even though it has 5 numbers in it.

**Pattern:**

```
^\s*Kd\s+.*(?:[-+]?0*\d*\.?\d*){3,4}$
```

**Samples:**

```
Kd   1.0  0.1   0.0
   Kd   .0  4.   01.
  Kd   .0  4.   01.  01.
 Kd   .0  4.   01. 01. 01.
    Kd   1.0  0.1   0.0  0.0
  Kd   1.0  0.1   0.0
```

**Expected captures:**

- 1.0, 0.1, 0.0
- .0, 4., 01.
- .0, 4., 01., 01.
- failure
- 1.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0
- 1.0, 0.1, 0.0

**Question:**

What am I doing wrong in the regex so it also matches lines with more than 4 floats in them?

Comment: I believe you should try again to debug the reason why `the 4th sample` matched. Had you put capture groups around your sub-expression `(?:[-+]?0*\d*\.?\d*){3,4}` you would realize it is not even a part of the regex that ever gets executed. Your regex is actually this [^\s*Kd\s+.*$](https://regex101.com/r/fH034g/1). Maybe you should try to help yourself out and use a better debug technique. The regex for float is not correct. By making everything optional, that float sub expression is useless. You need to find a good float regex as well.

Comment: @sln Thank you for the tips, going to make the most out of them and hopefully become a better regexer. As for the floats I guess you're right, I came up with it on my own and it's most certainly not the best in town!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is the `.*` part that matches any zero or more chars other than an LF char, as many times as possible. You also need to put `\s+` into the repeated group so as to allow whitespaces in between the numeric values.

You can use

```
^\s*Kd(?:\s+([-+]?(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.\d*))){3,4}$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5Cs*Kd%28%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%28%5B-%2B%5D%3F%28%3F%3A%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%7C%5Cd%2B%5C.%5Cd*%29%29%29%7B3%2C4%7D%5Cr%3F%24&i=Kd%20%20%201.0%20%200.1%20%20%200.0%0D%0A%20%20%20Kd%20%20%20.0%20%204.%20%20%2001.%0D%0A%20%20Kd%20%20%20.0%20%204.%20%20%2001.%20%2001.%0D%0A%20Kd%20%20%20.0%20%204.%20%20%2001.%2001.%2001.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Kd%20%20%201.0%20%200.1%20%20%200.0%20%200.0%0D%0A%20%20Kd%20%20%201.0%20%200.1%20%20%200.0&o=m). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `Kd` - a fixed string
- `(?:\s+([-+]?(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.\d*))){3,4}` - three to four occurrences of

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `([-+]?(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.\d*))` - Group 1:

    - `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
    - `(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.\d*)` - either zero or more digits, an optional `.` and one or more digits, or one or more digits, `.` and zero or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Works perfectly, I still need to decipher the subtle differences in your answer, though.